# Experimental resolution when measuring an oscillatory physical quantity

Tags: experimental-technique

Say, I want to sample a time-dependent quantity $c(t)$, the experimental resolution of this quantity is limited, denoted as $\delta c$; which means, to my knowledge, that if one wants to distinguish two consecutive quantities of the sampled $c(t)$, $c(t+\delta t)$, then $|c(t+\delta t)-c(t)|$ should be larger than $\delta c$.

But around some time $t_0$ when $c^\prime(t_0)=0$, this restriction cannot be satisfied, so where is the problem?

I feel that this is not a very good criterion for estimation. But I don't know where to find a better answer. Recently I have come across a similar problem, I can give an upper bound of $|c(t+\delta t)-c(t)| \lesssim \epsilon \delta t$, which I can ajust to exceed $\delta c$, but this still feels weird. What if $\epsilon$ is very small for some $t$?

In my problem, $c(t)$ is the output of some linear time invariant system with input $s(t)$, $C(\omega) = r(\omega)S(\omega)$, $C$, $S$ are the corresponding Fourier transforms, $r$ is the frequency response. If one cannot measure accuately the output $c(t)$, how can one retieve the input signal $s(t)$? What are the restrictions with various parameters, for example, the timestep $\delta t$, or the smallest $\delta c$ that can be measured?

Thanks very much for you help!

Comment: Your first sentence is technically correct, but there is usually no need to for consecutive measurements to yield distinguishable values. Where you thinking about a specific setup where this is the case?

Comment: @Daniel Thank you! My problem is that stated in the second-to-last paragraph. I have the measured output c(t), I need now to retrieve the input s(t). I want to find a criterion for the resolution when measuring c(t).

Comment: As stated in the third paragraph, I can now estimate an upper bound of two consecutive measured data that is larger than the smallest measurable c, but no lower bound. So what are the customary practices here? I am totally unfamiliar with this kind of problems. Thank you!